# how to change mac address by use python with windows xp environment

Tags: python, mac-address

i want to create python script which can change mac address in windows environment.

i can found bunch of some info about linux environment but

i couldn't found on windows environment.

if anyone help me much appreciate!

thanks in advance

Comment: Does Python get low enough in the stack to do this?  IIRC, this was only available via the network adapter driver--if at all.

Comment: If what I just read is right one could change mac address by changing appropriate key in windows registry, so it definitely is possible with Python.

Comment: would you tell me some sample or site ? thanks in advance!